# Can Bruna, Light of Alabaster take my opponent's auras?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Bruna, Light of Alabaster](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBruna%2c%20Light%20of%20Alabaster%5d) says:

> Whenever Bruna, Light of Alabaster attacks or blocks, you may attach to it any number of Auras on the battlefield and you may put onto the battlefield attached to it any number of Aura cards that could enchant it from your graveyard and/or hand

It appears that you could attach enchantments you do not control taking them from other creatures you do not control. Is this correct?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is true for all auras on the battlefield, regardless of their controller. There's no general rule that Auras can only be attached to their controller's own permanents, so Bruna can 'steal' other player's auras.
<sub>(They'd still control them, which is relevant e.g. for [Curious Obsession](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCurious%20Obsession%5d). This gives an ability to the enchanted creature, so **you** would get to draw a card if you 'steal' your opponents Curious Obsession with Bruna and deal combat damage to a player. But, as @Arthur notes in the comment, your **opponent** might not attack the next turn, which causes him/her to sacrifice the aura because he/she still controls it.)</sub>

You might think this is too powerful, but it really isn't; auras generally see little competitive play because they tend to lead to card disadvantage (if the enchanted creature dies, you'll lose two cards at once). And a multicolored six mana card should better win the game for you; it's supposed to be your 'finisher'. Commander is more about fun and long multiplayer games, so there this card certainly has more potential.

Comment: Note that if I attack with Bruna, and take an opponent's Curious Obsession, then I draw cards when Bruna deals combat damage to my opponent (because I control Bruna, and it is Bruna who gets the ability, meaning "you" refers to me), but my opponent may withold from attacking for a turn and the Obsession will be sacrificed (because my opponent still controls the Obsession, so _that_ "you" refers to him / her).

Comment: Good point, thanks. So this single card suffices to show some of the shenanigans about controlling auras :)

Comment: "auras generally see little competitive play because they tend to lead to card disadvantage." If the "card disadvantage" is the aura card, then this is just saying that auras aren't as good as other cards, making your statement "auras generally see little competitive play because they aren't as good as other cards". And since  Bruna takes cards from your graveyard, you don't have to draw the auras, you just have to get them into your graveyard.

Comment: Oh, if you play Bruna, you should definitely play a lot of auras in your deck. I'm just talking about the general picture; your opponent isn't likely to play many of them.

Comment: @Acccumulation generally when people are talking about card disadvantage from auras they are thinking of how you set yourself up for 2-for-1's. If an opponent removes your enchanted creature, they spent 1 card to remove two of your cards, that sort of thing. That isn't to say there aren't ways that aura's are designed to mitigate this (giving a powerful/card-advantage/protection effect etc.)